# Declaring variables in external script

Tags: bash

I'm tying to write a script which uses variables declared in another script.
I've tried so far using `export` to define environmental variables or just using local ones.

So I have my config script:

```
export DIR_STORAGE="/var/storage/"
```

And script trying to use it in the same directory:

```
source conf.sh
echo "DIR="${DIR_STORAGE}
```

but that doesn't seem to work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Works for me. What doesn't work?

Comment: don not forget to include shebangs in the beginning of your scirpts: #!/bin/bash -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) Also try to specify full path to conf.sh (for testing).

Comment: Hm, it worked with absolute path, thanks. Although this doesn't look like an elegant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you have both files in the same directory, `source conf.sh` will look for conf.sh in the *current directory*. For example:

```
SHELL$ pwd
/home/user

SHELL$ ls mydir/
script.sh conf.sh

SHELL$ mydir/script.sh
script.sh: line 1: conf.sh: No such file or directory
```

In this case, the script will look for 'conf.sh' in the current (home) directory, not under mydir.

To avoid this and always look for the config file in the same directory where the script is, a common practice is to use:

```
source "$(dirname $0)/conf.sh"
```

This will extract the path from the command you used to invoke the script and append the config file name to it; in the example above, this will become `source "mydir/conf.sh"` which should work fine.

P.S. If you use `source` there's no need to `export` any variables.